What is the right way to combine multiple flows without the debounce in one affecting the other?
I have two hypothetical streams of data intFlow and stringFlow that I want to combine and pipe to the UI. stringFlow is somewhat erratic so I am using debounce(2000) to "slow it down". However, the streams of data in intFlow come at a leisurely pace so it shouldn't be affected by this debouce call.
I have tried functions like combine() but it didn't work because intFlow waits for stringFlow which I don't want.
I also tried flatMapMerge{} but this too didn't work and unfortunately, I don't understand why because my understanding of this function is that it's asynchronous and the flows passed to it are not supposed to block each other.
I ended up using merge() but since the data types are different and I needed to later merge both data, I ended up using a hack:
val intFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
val stringFlow = MutableStateFlow("")

fun transform(result: suspend (s: String, i: Int) -> Flow<String>): Flow<String> {
    return merge(intFlow, stringFlow.debounce(2000))
        .map {
            if (it is Int) Pair(stringFlow.value, it) else Pair(it as String, intFlow.value)
        }
        .filter { (s, i) -> s.isNotBlank() && i > 0 }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { (s, i) -> result(s, i) }
//    return intFlow.flatMapMerge { i ->
//        stringFlow.debounce(2000).map { s -> Pair(s, i) }
//    }
//        .filter { (s, i) -> s.isNotBlank() && i > 0 }
//        .distinctUntilChanged()
//        .flatMapLatest { (s, i) -> result(s, i) }
}

val combinedFlow = transform { s, i ->
    return@transform flow {
        emit("$s::$i")
    }
}

fun getCurrentTime(): String {
    val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss:SSS")
    return currentDateTime.format(formatter) + " | ${
        currentDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    }"
}

suspend fun main() {
    val mainJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating String to 'a'")
        stringFlow.update { "a" }

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating Int to 1")
        intFlow.update { 1 }

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating String to 'a'")
        stringFlow.update { "a" }

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating Int to 2")
        intFlow.update { 2 }

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Delaying for 5 seconds")
        delay(5000)

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating String with 'b'")
        stringFlow.update { "b" }

        println("${getCurrentTime()} - Updating Int to 3")
        intFlow.update { 3 }
    }

    val collectJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        combinedFlow.collect {
            println("${getCurrentTime()} - Combined: $it-------- ")
        }
    }

    mainJob.join()
    collectJob.join()
}

This works but I am concerned about the hack:
.map {
     if (it is Int) Pair(stringFlow.value, it) else Pair(it as String, intFlow.value)
}

And if I could potentially run into concurrency issues like using stale data or something.
Using flatMapMerge{}, I get this output:
21:14:25:883 | 1713273265883 - Updating String to 'a'
21:14:25:891 | 1713273265891 - Updating Int to 1
21:14:25:892 | 1713273265892 - Updating String to 'a'
21:14:25:892 | 1713273265892 - Updating Int to 2
21:14:25:892 | 1713273265892 - Delaying for 5 seconds
21:14:27:929 | 1713273267929 - Combined: a::2-------- 
21:14:30:898 | 1713273270898 - Updating String with 'b'
21:14:30:899 | 1713273270899 - Updating Int to 3
21:14:32:910 | 1713273272910 - Combined: b::2-------- 
21:14:32:910 | 1713273272910 - Combined: b::3-------- 

And there's an about 2-second delay between when the int is published and when it's received.
Comparing this to merge():
21:15:54:969 | 1713273354969 - Updating String to 'a'
21:15:54:974 | 1713273354974 - Updating Int to 1
21:15:54:975 | 1713273354975 - Updating String to 'a'
21:15:54:975 | 1713273354975 - Updating Int to 2
21:15:54:975 | 1713273354975 - Delaying for 5 seconds
21:15:55:009 | 1713273355009 - Combined: a::2-------- 
21:15:59:986 | 1713273359986 - Updating String with 'b'
21:15:59:987 | 1713273359987 - Updating Int to 3
21:15:59:991 | 1713273359991 - Combined: b::3-------- 

And there's almost no delay between the publishing and receiving.

What do you mean by saying if used combine, then intFlow had to wait for stringFlow? combine emits whenever any flow emits, one flow shouldn't need to wait for another one. By your description it seems combine is exactly what you need.


I have tried functions like combine() but it didn't work because intFlow waits for stringFlow which I don't want.

This is not true, intFlow will not wait for stringFlow. A combined flow emits a new value when any of the underlying flows has a new value, not when all of them has emitted a new value.
This seems to be exactly the behavior that you need: The resulting flow will always emit when intFlow emits and will use the latest available value from stringFlow. On the other hand, when the debounced stringFlow eventually emits a new value, the resulting flow will now also emit.
The only restriction is that you must make sure that the debounced flow emits at least one value so that the combining can start. If you cannot easily refactor stringFlow to work like this you can always apply onStart after the debounce to emit an initial value before you combine it with intFlow.
